# Getting object with max date time value in one of it's properties

Tags: c#, linq

When I want to retrieve an object with the highest value in a `DateTime` property from an `IEnumerable`, I can do the following:

```
var maxDate = myEnumerable.Max(x => x.TheDateTimeProperty);
var wantedObject = myEnumerable.FirstOrDefault(x => x.TheDateTimeProperty == maxDate);
```

Is this possible without getting the `maxDate` first? For example like this:

```
var wantedObject = myEnumerable.GetByMaxDate(x => x.TheDateTimeProperty);
```

I know that I could write an extension method `GetByMaxDate`, but I want to know if there is already a method provided by linq.

**Just to clarify:** Not looking for other possibilities to write this. I was just interested if there exists a method that does it. (less code, best performance possible managed by the method)

Comment: You can use [morelinq](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) by Jon skeet and its method [MaxBy](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/MaxBy.cs?r=2da75c30d5bda7959e5113b702b4bb204a0e4a2c)

Comment: I second the notion that you should use the MaxBy method from morelinq. Should be in every C# programmer's toolbox!

Comment: So there is no build-in method by linq, thanks for the information about this one!

Comment: @Habib I guess that would be the answer

Comment: @PhilippM, I had it as an answer, but I guess it should more be a comment, Raphael's answer is more correct  IMO

Comment: @Habib see my edit - I think it is the answer to my question, that there is no built-in method but morelinq provides it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there are coming no other answers and there **doesn't** exist a **build-in** method in linq, I'll write down what I would use.

**For linq to objects:**

The method `MaxBy` from [morelinq](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) as mentioned by Habib in the comment.

**For linq to sql:**

I would write an extension method:

```
public static TSource SqlMaxBy<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> selector)
{   
  var maxValue = source.Max(selector);
  return source.FirstOrDefault(value => selector(value).Equals(maxValue));
}
```

**Update:**

In the .NET 9 Preview there was added a [MaxBy method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.maxby?view=net-9.0#system-linq-enumerable-maxby-2(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-system-func((-0-1)))).

Answer (score 14):

Pro : it should work with "any" linq provider (objects, entities, sql)

```
myEnumerable.OrderByDescending(x => x.TheDateTimeProperty).First();
```

Con : as pointed by Matthew Watson in comments, it won't be performant on (very) large lists.

Comment: This has the major disadvantage that it makes a copy of the entire sequence, then sorts it just to get the maximum value. Fine for small lists... very very bad for long lists.

Comment: @MatthewWatson absolutely. Just a question (if you've got the answer), does MaxBy work on all linq providers, like linq to entities ? With the source code given, it looks like it enumerates, which is... not great for an IQueryable.

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, this will get me the result, but I was interested if there is a method I can use that does it (with good performance)

Comment: @Raphaël Althaus: Alas, it will indeed enumerate; it's a shame there isn't a built-in one from Microsoft which would work efficiently with IQueryable.

Comment: @MatthewWatson well, I should have read better, morelinq clearly targets linq 2 objects. For the "shame", there's no MAXBY in ANSI SQL, and ANSI SQL lives since longer than linq to entities, so...

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to get the maxDate first like you have stated originally. I don't see any problem using the syntax you already used.

However if want you can shorthand the code like this:

```
var wantedObject = myEnumerable.FirstOrDefault(x => x.TheDateTimeProperty == myEnumerable.Max(x => x.TheDateTimeProperty));
```

(This code is not tested, maybe some type casting is needed)

Or you can write a stored procedure and take the data from that.

However I don't prefer OrderByDescending.First anymore. It is fine if physically your data in table is sorted ascending by your specified property. But if not, then your sql table will need to do descending sorting and probably get high load from it. Especially when the table has over than 1m record and the DateTime is stored ascending in the physical.

Use max can resulting better (faster/lightweight) result than it.

Comment: I didn't mean to ask, if there is another way without saving the maxDate in a variable first. I'll edit my question to clarify that.

Comment: Yes I know, just displaying the shorthand as additional.
As per my understanding, what you have accomplished already good and lightweight enough. Maybe you can get better answer if you described your problem with the syntax.
However when you like to achieve better, consider using stored procedure, where you can tune up the query or improve with indexes.

Comment: My question is not specifically about linq-to-sql, but if someone wants it in this context, this is good point!